# Woocommerce New Order Email Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

In Woocommerce, once customer place an order, the email notification that is sent has a Payment Instruction from the payment method itself. I would like to move the payment instruction below the order details like:

```
<p> Order Details </p>
<p> Payment Instruction </p>
```

How can I move the payment instruction below the order details ?

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php to your-child-theme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php  and find  do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); on line number 24 and move it below line number 87 or where you want this to show.

[image: order-email-image]